# ffmpeg blackdetect, start_black value to mkv chapter?

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

I'm trying to do automatic detect chapter with blackdetect with ffmpeg.

When I use blackdetect I get result but what is the result? Its not frames? Also. Is it possible to do a script/bat-file (for windows 10, powershell or cmd) to convert the result to a "mkv xml-file" so It can be imported with mkvtoolnix?

```
ffmpeg -i "movie.mp4" -vf blackdetect=d=0.232:pix_th=0.1 -an -f null - 2>&1 | findstr black_duration > output.txt
```

result:

```
 black_start:2457.04 black_end:2460.04 black_duration:3
 black_start:3149.46 black_end:3152.88 black_duration:3.41667
 black_start:3265.62 black_end:3268.83 black_duration:3.20833
 black_start:3381.42 black_end:3381.92 black_duration:0.5
 black_start:3386.88 black_end:3387.38 black_duration:0.5
 black_start:3390.83 black_end:3391.33 black_duration:0.5
 black_start:3824.29 black_end:3824.58 black_duration:0.291667
 black_start:3832.71 black_end:3833.08 black_duration:0.375
 black_start:3916.29 black_end:3920.29 black_duration:4
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation on this function [here](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blackdetect). Specifically this line:

> Output lines contains the time for the start, end and duration of the detected black interval expressed in seconds.

If you read further down the page you will see another function `blackframe` which does a similar thing but outputs the frame number rather than seconds.

If the mkvtoolnix xml file has a chapter definition facility you will be able to create a script that takes the ffmpeg output and dumps it into the correct format in any language of your choice.

Comment: So It is minutes, a bit wierd. However. Mkvtoolnix only handle chapter by time "00:00:00.000000000" not by frames. I have read but I'm still confused. I can not figure it out how to convert "black_start:3149.46 black_end:2460.04" to "00:52.491000000" or what it might be?

Comment: You extract the black start number using regex or what ever string manipulation method you are comfortable with. Then convert the 2460 in to hours mins secs format matching mkvtoolnix. You could do this with simple math or perhaps using a timespan function. If you have a specific issue or barrier with your code you should post it as a specific question. I have given you plenty of concepts to research and I dont want to write the code for you.